# How do I get the system to read the entire capacity of my drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I removed a 40GB hard drive from a laptop and connected it to my other laptop via USB, but the system shows the drive as only a 24.9GB capacity drive.  I know it is a 40GB hard drive... it is a Hitachi Travelstar HTS541040Q9AT00 40GB drive.

Comment: Does it perhaps have more than one partition, and you're only seeing one of them? Check it in Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc), or if you're using Linux, GParted or similar partition editor. Speaking of OS, which one are you using? And what filesystem does the hard drive use?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I checked it out in Disk Manager and sure enough there were actually 4 different partitions.  I removed them and created 1 new partition.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. I posted my comment as an answer; consider accepting it so others who find this question will know what helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the hard drive has more than one partition, and you're only seeing one of them.

In Windows, you can use Disk Management (`diskmgmt.msc`), on Linux you can use GParted or similar partition editor.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your hard drive has multiple partitions.
Here's a link that explains disk management, assuming you're on windows

http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-vista/how-to-use-disk-management-in-vista/